# I cannot figure out why my html page is not running my external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, atom-editor

> I have two javascript functions called CalculateFV() which is used to calculate my future value by grabbing the inputs from the processEntries() function and then display the result in the future_value text box on the HTML page but I currently cannot see why it is not functioning correctly and the button is not working to calculate my result
> I am also using atom as my editor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Future Value Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="future_value.css">
    <script src="future_value.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Future Value Calculator</h1>

        <label for="investment">Total Investment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="investment"><br>

        <label for="rate">Annual Interest Rate:</label>
        <input type="text" id="rate">%<br>

        <label for="years">Number of Years:</label>
        <input type="text" id="years"><br>

        <label for="future_value">Future Value:</label>
        <input type="text" id="future_value" disabled><br>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
     var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        };
        
        var calculateFV = function(investment_amount, interest_rate, number_of_years){
          var futureValue;
          futureValue = investment_amount
          for(var i = 1; i <= number_of_years; i++){
            futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * interest_rate / 100);
          }
          return futureValue;
        }
        
        var processEntries = function(){
          var investment_amount = $("investment").value;
          var interest_rate = $("rate").value;
          var number_of_years = $("years").value;
        
          $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment_amount, interest_rate, number_of_years);
        }
        
        window.onLoad = function(){
          $("calculate").value = processEntries;
          $("investment").focus();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onLoad` function wasn't being handled correctly and you need to register a `click` listener on the calculate button. Try this:

`future_value.js:`

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var calculateFV = function(investment_amount, interest_rate, number_of_years){
  var futureValue;
  futureValue = investment_amount
  for(var i = 1; i <= number_of_years; i++){
    futureValue = futureValue + (futureValue * interest_rate / 100);
  }
  return futureValue;
}

var processEntries = function(){
  var investment_amount = $("investment").value;
  var interest_rate = $("rate").value;
  var number_of_years = $("years").value;

  $("future_value").value = calculateFV(investment_amount, interest_rate, number_of_years);
}

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  $('calculate').addEventListener('click', processEntries);
  $("investment").focus();
});
```

Using this I see the future value input populated after I click calculate. Note the changes I made towards the bottom.